# Spectral lower bounds on the diameter of a graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

There is such a bound, due to Mohar and McKay, using the second-smallest eigenvalue of the Laplacian $\lambda_{2}$:

$$Diam \geq \lceil \frac{4}{n\lambda_{2}} \rceil.$$

This bound is very elegant but it is not very strong, as far as I can tell (for example, among the 11117 connected graphs on 8 vertices it only achieves the value $3$ for fifty (50) graphs, whereas there are actually 6962 graphs whose diameter is at least three; even for those fifty graphs, the estimate is not sharp, as they all actually have diameter at least 4).

> Are there known bounds of this kind which significantly improve upon
>   the Mohar-McKay bound?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the bound is sharp for $K_n$ and $P_3$.

There aren't other small sharp cases according to my search.